# PublishSubject - is there a way to execute something onNext()?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

PublishSubject is great to have a bridge between an observer and an observable:

```
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("string");

    PublishSubject<String> observer1 = PublishSubject.<String>create();

    Observer<Object> observer2 = new Observer<Object>() {...}

    // observer2 will receive all onNext and onCompleted events from observer1
    observer1.subscribe(observer2);

    //observer1 will get items from observable and propagate them to observer2
    observable.subscribe(observer1);
```

However it kind of lacks a functionality to do something appart from being a bridge, I mean it would come in handy to be able to do something like:

```
PublishSubject<String> observer1 = PublishSubject.<String>create()
    .doOnNext( item ->  System.out.println("Do something with the item " + item) );
```

But the compiler complaints: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Observable<String> to PublishSubject<String>`.

Is there a way to decorate a PublishSubject to do something on next()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such decorations don't really work in practice. Just keep a reference to the original `PublishSubject` and hand out the `Observable` the `doOnNext` returns.

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.<String>create()

Observable<String> source = subject
   .doOnNext( item ->  System.out.println("Do something with the item " + item) );

source.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);

subject.onNext("1");
```